# Cannot open stdio.h

Tags: visual-studio

I upgraded Visual Studio from Community 2015 to Community 2017. Now when I build I get error messages saying 'Error (active)    E1696   cannot open source file "stdio.h"' The referenced line looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

If I create a new project, stdio.h is found.

So I looked at the project Configuration Properties->VC++ Directories and I see this:

```
Include Directories  $(VC_IncludePath);$(WindowsSDK_IncludePath);
```

So it seems that VC_IncludePath needs to be set but I can't find any place to set that. Note that I can't find Macro's and it may be because I'm using the free version of Visual Studio 2017.

Can someone please make a suggestion?

Comment: You can only get help when you tell us as much as possible, we can't see your screen from here.  That same dialog also shows "Evaluated value" with a list of directories.  What do you see?  You *should* see the ucrt subdirectory in that list, does that directory actually exist on your disk?

Comment: If I use Edit on Include Directories I do see "Evaluated value". (I didn't notice that). I see it is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.10.25017\include" I'll get back with you after I investigate that.

Comment: There is no ucrt in the list. I checked "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.10.25017\include" and there is no stdio.h. On my computer, I do see stdio.h in a directory called "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.14393.0\ucrt". So, as I originally stated, my problem is that I don't see how to set the macro VC_IncludePath.

Comment: Remember, the problem occurs when I try to open a solution created in 2015 but I'm using 2017. VS 2017 will convert the solution from 2015 to 2017 and that is what causes the problem. Note also that if I create a new solution using 2017 the standard .h's are found. I could fix this by re-creating all of my 2015 solutions under 2017 but I have lots of 2015 solutions and I don't want to re-create each one. Note that I am also using Community 2017 which may be why this VS problem has not been spotted already.

Comment: @Hans Passant, I did find "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" in the directory list.  But I don't have a directory called "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" (i.e., Include does not have 10.0.10240, it has "10.0.14393.0" instead. It is odd ... I made a copy of "10.0.14393.0" to "10.0.10240.0" but the standard includes are still not found (e.g. stdio.h).

Comment: Give us the output of `dir c:\stdio.h /s/b`

Answer (score 18):

Seems like the Windows SDK Version you're trying to use is not installed on your PC. You should check the used SDK Version of your Project (in Properties) which can be changed to 10.0.14393.0

Also you can run your Visual Studio installer again and click Modify on your VS17 Version, go to Advanced and check if the required SDK is marked. If not mark it and install it.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. You would think that Microsoft would have tried using a 2015 solution in the new 2017 and fixed that problem properly.

Comment: Mark it as "the answer" by clicking on the green check mark.

Comment: in my case I installed VS17 on a windows 8.1 machine and it automatically only downloaded and installed the Windows10 SDK, I had to expressly modify and select the Windows 8.1 SDK.