# Visual Studio failed to create C++ Console app

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I was going to create a new C++ console app. When I created a C++ console app, I encountered 3 errors. They have same error code, which is E1696.

- the source file "stdio.h" can not be opened
- the source file "tchar.h" can not be opened
- the source file "SDKDDKVer.h" can not be opened

Comment: None of the above are source files.  If you get theses errors straight after creating a new console project then I suggest you run "Repair" from the installer.

Comment: Or: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43306266/cannot-open-stdio-h